# Darcula dark theme for Eclipse

Tags: 12.04, themes, eclipse, ide

I wonder if there is a way to use Android Studio Darcula theme in Eclipse? I am trying to make Eclipse look a little bit like AS. So far I have made changes to the editor window and I have no idea how to tackle the rest of window frames etc. Any ideas?

Comment: This question is [off-topic](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). Consider asking it on [su] or [unix.se].

Comment: no, this is not off topic.  Any software being used on Linux is on topic...

Comment: @Thufir Clearly on topic, however Android Studio is currently not built on Eclipse. It's based on the IntelliJ platform and the existing functionality of IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition. There's not much functionality in reopening such an out of date question. PM me in [Raiders of the Lost Downboat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3877/raiders-of-the-lost-downboat) chatroom if you disagree.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Android Studio is built on Eclipse. Please see these links for creating and understanding an Eclipse theme:

1. [Eclipse 4 CSS](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/CSS)
2. [Eclipse theme tutorial](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2010/08/05/eclipse-4-0-so-you-can-theme-me-part-1/)
3. [How to create a basic Eclipse 4 theme](http://blog.vogella.com/2012/07/11/eclipse-4-is-beautiful-create-your-own-eclipse-4-theme/)

What you want to do is basically understand how a theme is created and how to edit the basic Android Studio theme. Keep in mind that AS will probably use different classes. Check the dropins and plugins folders for the AS theme.

Comment: missing link: http://blog.vogella.com/2012/07/11/eclipse-4-is-beautiful-create-your-own-eclipse-4-theme/

Comment: You can edit your answer and paste link there.

Comment: You are wrong. Android Studio is  based on JetBrains' popular IntelliJ IDEA software

Comment: @Danatela I couldn't post more than 2 links with 0 rep,
lunar you are right, the links I provided are still useful if you could dig a bit into how IDEA themes work